# Visual Basic: run specific codes from exe file

Tags: vb.net, command-line

How can i run specific codes from an exe file?

For example;

Target for a shortcut which runs an mp3 file;
"C:/thing/something.exe -music"

Target for a shortcut which runs an bmp file;
"C:/thing/something.exe -picture"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you can do is read the command line arguments inside you program when it starts then parse those inputs to make a decision.

For example:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Dim CommandLineArgs As System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection(Of String) = My.Application.CommandLineArgs

    If (String.Compare(CommandLineArgs(0), "-picture") = 0) Then
        'desired code to do something for a picture here

    ElseIf (String.Compare(CommandLineArgs(0), "-music") = 0) Then
        'desired code to do something for music here

    End If

End Sub
```

If you gave the input -music C:\filepath\filename.mp3 then CommandLineArgs(0) would be -music and CommandLineArgs(1) would be C:\filepath\filename.mp3.  From this you could pass CommandLineArgs(1) to another program of your choice to play the file (or use some built in method to play it).